# Setting Loading Message duration in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile `$.mobile.loading()` method to display different messages to my users, I am oso I use a function:

```
function show_screen_msg(msg) {
  $.mobile.loading('show',{ text:msg, textVisible:true, textonly:true });
}

show_screen_msg('ok');
```

For example I use it when the user updates his profile on database;
I want to set the time the message is displayed on the screen.
Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: `setTimeout(function () { $.mobile.loading("hide"); }, 10000);` this will hide loading msg after 10secs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this function as told by Omar.But normally we use this loading functionality to keep users waiting while all the back end network delays and operations are done.I guess you might be running locally so you are not seeing these delays. So specifying an explicit timeout function might not be the best thing you want. 
    For example if you use ajax requests to update the database get the response back and hide the loading if success.

```
$.ajax(
{
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   $.mobile.loading("hide");
});
```